# User post limits to be included in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, faq-update-request, rate-limiting

[The FAQ for a Stack Exchange 1.0 site](http://ask.antimoon.com/faq) includes the time rate limits for posting that was a direct result of the [Australia incident](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/):

> 15    Flag offensive

> 100   Vote down (costs 1 rep), ask more than one question every 20 minutes, answer more than one question every 2 minutes

Do you think this information should be included in [the FAQ for Stack Exchange 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), or should it be left as it is?

---

Friday bonus:

The same Stack Exchange 1.0 site FAQ includes this for 100,000 reputation:

> 100000    Stop speeding bullets, jump over small buildings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bad idea, but I don't actually want these limits to be so public.