# The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide

Tags: support, faq, rate-limiting

I noticed that I can only perform certain actions such as commenting a finite number of times in a given period of time. Obviously, rate limiting is in place to prevent accidental misuse or intentional abuse of certain features.

Where else is rate limiting applied on Stack Exchange sites, and what are the limits?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: I thought this information was somewhat of a secret. See [the answer to *User post limits to be included in the FAQ?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55069/user-post-limits-to-be-included-in-the-faq/56102#56102).

Comment: @Peter: What Jeff "wants" is no longer relevant. :)

Answer (score 334, accepted):

### [Rate Limit Rationale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32202)

### Loading pages

- [Undisclosed limit, applies to IP addresses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268446/are-page-requests-rate-limited-throttled)

  - Applies to the entire network; if one makes too many requests on one or more sites, access to all network sites is restricted
  - Does not apply to non-load-balanced services not served from the same network as public Q&A (chat, the API, etc.)
  - Should not be triggered during normal browsing; if you get it, it either means you're sharing your IP with multiple users accessing the network, or your browser or an extension is hitting the site with one or more extra requests every time you load a page

> [image: Too many requests: This IP address has performed an unusual high number of requests and has been temporarily rate limited.]

### Comments

- Voting & Flagging

  - Same amount of comment flags as one does post flags (default 10, may rise up to 100 based on flagging activity or reputation; see *Flagging* below)

    - Comment flag and post flag allowances are separate
  - [30 comment upvotes per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238331) (automatic upvotes resulting from close votes [do not count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358813/why-do-auto-upvotes-on-close-vote-comments-count-towards-the-daily-limit/378783#378783))
  - no minimum wait time between votes

    [image: Comment voting - Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 3 hours]
  - Can only flag one comment every 5 seconds
- Deleting ([treated like voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14185))

  - No limit per second (previous one-comment-per-5-second limit removed)
  - Can only delete own upvoted comments under 20 posts per day (multiple comments under same post are treated as one)
    [image: You have already deleted your own comments from 20 posts today; further deletes are blocked]

    - Despite what the message says, you can [still delete an unlimited number of non-upvoted comments per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272766/377214), even if you've hit the above rate limit.
- Creating

  - [Three comments per 30 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250994/throttle-comment-button-to-prevent-double-submission/251005?noredirect=1#comment819750_251005)

  [image: Comment creation - You may add another comment in 24 seconds]
- Editing

  - comment can be edited every 5 seconds by its author or a diamond mod
    [image: Comment editing - You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds]
  - comments cannot be edited after 5 minutes (except by diamond moderators)

### Searching

- [No rate limits for humans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100) is what was stated, but [testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166034) has shown it to be 30 searches in 60 seconds (see comment on answer linked to).

  [image: Searching - You may only perform 30 searches within a 60 second window]

- Anonymous users

  - [are limited to a maximum of 500 results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342633)
  - [can only search for three tags at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342645/377214) (was previously limited to one tag, but later raised)
  - [must solve a CAPTCHA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355670/search-changes-for-anonymous-users) unless they've already solved one in the last five minutes

### Asking

- Users with < 125 rep on the current site, [40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) (This applies to the user's IP address, *not* their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network; similarly, if the same user posts a question from a different IP address, [they may not be limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341711/377214).)

  [image: Question limit - You can only post once every 40 minutes]

  - Other per-site limits may apply; e.g. on Stack Overflow, new users can only ask once every 90 minutes. Some of these per-site limits do also check the account, not just the IP address.
  - While the limit is waived for users with 125+ reputation on a given site, questions posted on sites where one has 125+ reputation still count toward the rate limit for sites where one doesn't. For instance, if you ask a question on a site where you have 150 rep, you can't ask another question on a site where you have only 100 rep for the next 40 minutes; however, you can ask them in reverse order immediately (first on the 100-rep site, then on the 150-rep site).
- Users limited by [Anti-Recidivism System](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610), one question per week
- Users limited from asking questions for 1 – 7 days [based on the performance of their previous questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)
- Users prevented from asking questions due to the quality filter: one question per 6 months
- Users with < 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 60 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
- Users with ≥ 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 30 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
- On Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Mathematics (not active on all other sites)

  - maximum of 6 questions per day
  - [maximum of 50 questions per 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217), on a [rolling basis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit#comment353092_89230) (50 questions in past 720 hours before current time).

  > Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period
- Stack Exchange staff members [are not subject to these rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344146/what-privileges-and-tools-do-staff-members-without-a-diamond-have-access-to) on meta sites

### Answering

- Users with < 125 rep must [wait 3 minutes between answers on most Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23038), but [must wait 30 minutes between answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit). The longer wait time between answers on Stack Overflow was implemented as part of the [response to a flood of ChatGPT answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991).
- Users with between 125 and 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 60 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
- Users with ≥ 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 30 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
- Users of any reputation level can only answer the *same* question once every 60 seconds
- Users with the "staff" bit (i.e. Stack Exchange employees) [are not subject to the above limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344146/what-privileges-and-tools-do-staff-members-without-a-diamond-have-access-to) on meta sites

### Accepting

- [All must wait 15 minutes after asking to accept any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44099)
- [All must wait 48 hours after asking to accept *own* answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

  [image: You can accept an answer in 4 minutes]

### Editing

- Edit at most 10 of one's *own* posts per day (can be modified per site, but no site has modified it)

  - Additional edits to the same post aren't counted
  - Edits to posts created [on the same or previous UTC calendar day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367539/377214) don't count
  - Edits made to posts scoring -1 or lower don't count
  - Edits to deleted posts don't count
  - Once the limit is hit, no more edits can be made to *any* of one's own posts, even if the edit would be exempt per the above criteria
  - Does not apply to ♦ moderators, users with the moderator tools privilege ("10k+" users), or Stack Exchange staff members
  - Rollbacks aren't considered edits for any of the above checks

  > You have already edited 10 of your own posts today; further edits are not allowed until tomorrow

  (Source: [What exactly is the rate limit for editing your own posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335594/377214))
- At most [5 pending suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202) per editor (20 on beta sites)

  - Limit is partially waived if submitting a tag wiki and excerpt suggested edit at the same time (which counts as two edits) - if the user only has space for one more pending edit, both edits will still be allowed, but they cannot submit another suggested edit until *two* of their pending edits are approved (i.e. they're no longer exceeding the limit)
- Unregistered users can't suggest edits on posts < 10 minutes old
- Users with < 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 30 seconds, or faster than 5 seconds after starting edit
- Users with ≥ 10k rep [trip CAPTCHA*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2293) if more than once per 10 seconds, or faster than 5 seconds after starting edit
- You can only save a tag wiki edit once every 30 seconds, or once every 10 seconds if you have enough reputation (20k/4k on beta sites) to bypass the review queue. (Submitting a tag wiki edit along with a tag wiki *excerpt* edit at the same time for the same tag is not limited.)

* For all of the above thresholds for hitting CAPTCHA, if you have at least 200 reputation and have solved a CAPTCHA in the last 5 minutes, you will not have to solve one again.

### Flagging

- [10 flags per day by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890)

  - 1 bonus daily flag for every 10 net helpful flags in the user's flagging history (helpful minus declined, excluding other types such as disputed and aged away)
  - 1 bonus daily flag for every 2,000 reputation earned
  - A net negative helpful flag count can reduce a user's daily flag allowance to below 10
  - The number of daily flags is hard-capped at 100
- 5 seconds between flags (both flagging and retracting)
- 3 seconds between opening the flag dialog

  [image: You can only flag for moderator attention 48 times a day]

  [image: You may only flag a post every 5 seconds]

  [image: You may only load the flag dialog every 3 seconds]
- You can be banned from flagging when [too many flags have been declined in a 7 day period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405); such a ban will automatically be lifted once the criteria no longer apply (after at most 7 days).

### Reviewing

- [20 reviews per queue per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147981) if the queue size is less than 1000 (150 on Stack Overflow)
- [40 reviews per queue per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152233) if the queue size is 1000 or more (150 on Stack Overflow)
- [80 reviews per First Questions queue per day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412077) if the queue size is 1000 or more on Stack Overflow
- Reviews on suggested edits to your own posts do count toward the limit if you haven't reached it yet, but will be allowed through even if you have.
- No review limit for ♦ mods

> Thank you for reviewing 20 Close Votes today; come back tomorrow to continue reviewing.

### Chat

- 1 second between two messages, here's the true throttle curve

[image: Chat Throttle Curve]

- There is a similar throttle for starring (details unknown)
- There is a similar throttle for searching (details unknown)
- Star limit is [20 stars per room, per day](/a/236370) for each user.
- 30 seconds between creating chat bookmarks

> [image: You can perform this action again in 21 seconds]

### Voting

- 30 votes per day +10 for questions only (question-only votes can't be used once you've cast 25 votes on answers) ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213))

  - To further elaborate: you get 10 Q-votes and 30 QA-votes per day. When you vote on a question, you'll use a Q-vote, and on an answer, you'll use a QA-vote. If you run out of Q-votes, you can continue voting on questions, but you'll be using QA-votes. However, once you have only 5 QA-votes left, you'll be blocked from using your Q-votes and all of your remaining voting for the day will use your QA-votes.
- If one of the posts you vote on gets deleted the same day as you vote, your limit is recalculated as if you never cast that vote (i.e. in most cases, you can cast one more vote, but if you now have more than 5 unused QA-votes, your Q-votes will be unblocked, allowing you to vote more times).
- If you vote and undo your vote 30 times, your vote gets locked in.

[image: You have voted and undone your vote too many times. Your vote is now locked in]

### Logging in

- 3 failed attempts within a minute before a CAPTCHA is displayed

### Changing usernames

- Last username change must be less than 15 minutes or [more than 30 days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38180). Does not apply to ♦ mods or accounts that are less than 2 days old.

### Showing Upvote/Downvote totals

- [once per second](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35488)

[image: You may only fetch vote counts once every second]

### Expanding revision history from user activity

- once per second

  [image: You may only load 1 revision every second]

### Closing

- Can open close dialog once per 3 seconds
- 50 close/reopen votes/day/user on Stack Overflow, Mathematics, Server Fault, Super User and Ask Ubuntu, 12 on Stack Apps, 24 on others. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/)

[image: You may only load the close dialog every 3 seconds]

### Deleting

- Can only delete 5 of your own posts per day

  - Undeleting and re-deleting the same post on the same day won't count
  - Posts that were made on the same UTC calendar day or the previous UTC calendar day don't count
  - Posts that score -1 or lower don't count
  - Once the limit is reached, no more posts can be deleted, even if they'd be exempt per the above bullets
  - Doesn't apply to diamond moderators
- [5 delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105876) (at 10k) with an extra delete vote for every 1k rep above 10k, max of 30, per day

  - When a 10k+ user with delete votes remaining deletes one of their own posts, that deletion [will deduct 1 from their delete votes for the day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274832/2157772).
  - Other than that, the counts between self-deleted posts and delete votes for others' posts are kept separate: the number of self-deleted posts is limited to 5 per the above criteria, and if you've used all your delete votes but have not hit the above limit, you can still delete your own posts up until the limit (the counter will show as negative).
- Question must be closed in order to be able to vote to delete it
- A question can't be voted to delete until 2 days after closure, [unless 20k+](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70044) and question score [-3 or lower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675)
- Can only cast one delete vote and one undelete vote on the same post, except when you are the post owner or a moderator.

  - If you previously deleted or undeleted someone else's post as a moderator, you cannot vote to delete or undelete the post again if you later cease to be a moderator.

### Deleting/destroying accounts

- Moderators can delete/destroy only one account every 5 seconds.

### Winter Bash hats

- Change hat once every 10 seconds

[image: You may only change your hat once every 10 seconds]

### iOS and Android apps (deprecated)

- Due to depending on the API, one second between actions
  [image: First line: "Error". Second line: "You cannot perform this action for another 1 seconds". Third line: "OK"]
- *Unlike* the normal API, which restricts users to 10,000 queries per day (see below), the iOS app [is allowed a (theoretically) unlimited number of queries per day](https://stackapps.com/q/8168/27674) (restricted to `2^31 - 1` or 2,147,483,647, or the maximum number for a 32-bit signed integer). This does not apply to the Android app.

  - Note that this is likely to change given that app-specific API features are gradually being retired due to the discontinuation of the apps.

### Stack Exchange API

- API request quotas

  - Request quotas are the maximum number of API requests in a rolling 24-hour period.
  - Maximum of 300 queries per 24 hours per IP address, if not using an API `key` value. Requests with an API `key` also count against this quota. It is not separate from the 10k quota, which means these 300 requests are likely to be consumed by applications using an API `key`.
  - Maximum of 10,000 queries per day per API `key` and IP address pair, if using a per-application API `key`, with some exceptions:

    - Some high-profile tools that actively help out with the Stack Exchange network receive special keys that grant them an extended limit (e.g., SmokeDetector has a limit of 80,000)
    - The above noted exemption for the iOS app, which has a special key that doesn't have daily API limits (see above section for more details)
    - The quota which is applied to the IP address is the same for all API requests made with a `key` value in the 24-hour period. The quota value which is used is the maximum quota assigned to any `key` which is used to make a request from that IP address within that 24 hour period (e.g., if a `key` with a 50k quota is used for a single request on the IP address, then all requests with a valid `key` value from that IP address in that 24 hour period have a 50k quota, regardless of what their normal quota would be).
  - Requests which use an `access_token`, in addition to a `key`, use a quota which is tied to the `access_token`. An `access_token` uniquely identifies an application + user pair. Each *user* has up to 5 additional 10,000 request quota pools which are allocated separately to the first 5 application + user pairs used for that user in a 24-hour period. Requests made with an `access_token` do *not* count against the IP based quotas.
- A hard limit of 30 requests from any IP address per second. SE considers "[> 30 request/sec per IP to be very abusive and thus cut the requests off very harshly.](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle)" In normal operation, requests will almost always be throttled in other ways well before that hard limit.
- Occasionally, queries can return a `backoff` value, to indicate how much time a given application needs to wait before it can perform another query. This value depends on the number and speed of the queries and the overall load on SE's servers, and can change based on various other factors. The exact criteria used for issuing a `backoff` are not disclosed.
- SE uses multiple layers of rate limiting for the SE API. The criteria used for the rate limiting layers are not disclosed. Rate limiting is implemented both by the above mentioned `backoff` response and requests returning various errors, potentially with no additional information.

Comment: How are rate limits for non-humans implemented?  Is a count of searches within a short period of time (lets say 5 seconds) calculated each time someone does a search?

Comment: Why are there even limits on the diamond mods?

Comment: @LanceRoberts What does "timer resets" mean, Sir?

Comment: @AveMaleficum, when you vote on a comment, a timer starts.  Everytime you click on the vote or flag button instead of having a smaller amount of time left, the timer resets itself.  So you end up trying to time things in your head waiting for it to expire, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164051/13295).

Comment: There's also a limit for page requests per IP address per time period which I think must have recently been tightened (saw it twice yesterday) but I don't know what the exact limit is.

Comment: Shouldn't per IP throttling occur only for anonymous users? IMO all API calls within the page should have a token associated with them and be throttled per user.

Comment: What is the point of throttling per action with respect to DoS as opposed to global rate-limiting?

Comment: ...yay, another [1 secondS](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105). Why is it so hard to not fix *all of these* once and for all?

Comment: @Werner You linked to the tweet that answers your question.

Comment: @michaelb958: Sadly it doesn't answer it. It just gives Jeff's opinion about these things. There are so many quantifiers on this website and I wonder why nobody ever takes to time to consider the singular/plural issue from the start... It seems as simple as writing a function where you pass it the quantity and it will return either an "s" or nothing and append that to the quantifier. It seems so fundamentally straight-forward.

Comment: @Werner Jeff was the original CTO, and the pluralisation code was written under his watch (if not by him), so his opinion carries a little more weight. The current team could fix them now if it justified the resources, and if they weren't scared of the giant S. (They might be fixing them *right now*, and they just haven't told us yet so Jeff doesn't find out until that security upgrade's done.)

Comment: @LanceRoberts How should the chat throttle chart be interpreted? What's the data used to generate it?

Comment: @Shadow, any reference on the comment rate-limit changes?

Comment: @Lance trial and error following this [bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250994/throttle-comment-button-to-prevent-double-submission) - asked the dev for confirmation.

Comment: @Werner, perhaps they should use MediaWiki's [jquery.i18n](https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n).

Comment: @Pro huh, looks like a new feature! I'm pretty sure I played with it once, voting and unvoting at least 10 times. That said, without the exact limit, I'm not sure it belongs here, e.g. post ban is not mentioned in this faq.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hmm, I see. I thought it belonged here, even while I don't have the exact details (I had seen others with "details unknown"), so feel free to remove it if it actually doesn't belong here. (also I'm pretty sure I clicked more than 10 times)

Comment: Anyone know what the rate limiting for page loads is?

Comment: I did in fact hit the "loading pages" limit multiple times in the past during "normal browsing". But that was usually opening a lot of pages in new tabs and then going through them one by one. Usually by the time I went through all open ones, I was already unblocked and could open the next batch. So it was just a slight inconvenience every time. Also: "unusualLY hight number of requests".

Comment: The 40 minutes restriction relating to IP does not seem capable to defend a VPN. Maybe restriction by account is even better.

Comment: Logging in multiple times in a short space of time seems to give you a CAPTCHA too.

Comment: @bad_coder I've rolled back your recent edit here. The post you linked as a reference said the opposite of the text you added here, so I'm not sure what you were intending.

Comment: @Makyen what is the limit to editing other users posts? I read the said posts several times and that's as best I could understand them.

Comment: @bad_coder What you wrote here is that editing other people's posts is limited based on reputation. The answer you linked, [answer to: How many edits can a high-rep user have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224726/271271), explicitly states there's no limit to editing other people's posts, but that there is a limit to editing your own posts.

Comment: The graph for chat rate limiting seems to be incorrect. I was able to pretty close to 40s, making me think that the cooldown has been doubled.

Comment: _Should not be triggered during normal browsing; if you get it, it either means you're sharing your IP with multiple users accessing the network_ I'm behind corporate network and there will be potentially hundreds of users accessing stackoverflow from the same IP address. We get the Loading pages rate limit fairly often with normal usage, is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones This isn't the correct place to document *character* limits; this is only for *rate* limits (i.e. cases where a user can only take an action at a certain frequency). The correct place for *character* limits is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372184/an-incomplete-character-limiting-guide-to-stack-exchange), and everything you've added here is mentioned there.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog  Thanks, I wasn't sure.  I saw answer length limits mentioned (`Maximum of 30000 characters for the Markdown source of answer`), and thought it was a bit strange that question limits weren't mentioned, so I added them in, and then kept going.

Comment: @Undo I assume to prevent chaos in case of account compromises. Someone could script deleting every user. Before you get to the 1000th user, with a rate limit of 5 seconds (that's ~1.4 hours), it probably has been noticed and access temporarily revoked, and then the cleanup can begin but is at least more limited in scope than if you were able to do a hundred requests per second from any old internet connection.